Access Firestore subcollection in Flutter
I have a Flutter chat application.
The structure of FireStore is:
chats (collection) > roomId (random generated id, which is a document) > users (collection) > email (email of the user, which is a document) > messages (collection) > messageId (random generated id, which is a document) > the actual chat.
When I use the following code it works. This gives all the messages in a room by a particular user.
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),

However, I need to get a list of all the users in a room. This is the code that I tried and is not getting any result, empty list.
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> userCollection = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chats')
          .doc(roomId)
          .collection('users')
          .get();

Here is the rule that is set on the store.
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

I need to get the list of all the users in the room.
Any help is appreciated.
Updated code that worked
I updated the code that I used to send message to FireStore.
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats').doc(widget.roomId).set({
      'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(widget.rooomId)
        .collection('users')
        .doc(widget.user)
        .set({
      'joinedAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(widget.roomId)
        .collection('users')
        .doc(widget.user)
        .collection('messages')
        .add({
      'senderId': widget.user,
      'text': _messageController.text,
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'isAdmin': widget.isAdmin
    });


We can't see the contents of your database, so we don't know what that query is supposed to return.  If you edit the question to show the relevant contents, especially what you expect the query to return, it will be easier for someone to see what the problem might be.

If you're getting an empty result, the operation is allowed by your security rules - so those aren't the cause of the empty list.
More likely, you don't actually have any documents in the /chats/$roomId/user collection. Keep in mind:

The Firestore console/web interface shows document IDs in italic for any path where no document actually exists, but there is lower-level content under that document.
The Firestore API only returns a document snapshot when a document actually exists in that path. So it does not return a document snapshot when the document ID is shown in italic.

If this is indeed the cause of your problem, the normal way out is to create a document for each user. It doesn't have to have much (or even any) fields, but the document needs to exist. Alternatively/additionally, you can use a document group query on the lower-level collections, to see if you can reconstitute the users from that.
For more on this, also see:

Firestore DB - documents shown in italics
Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?
Firestore query returns no documents even though they are shown in the console in italics


Thanks for the answer, that was very useful.

I was able to resolve this issue, for the people who might be following my footsteps in the future, I am providing the solution here that worked for me.
